# Drupal escaping url in dynamically created meta tags

Tags: php, drupal, character-encoding, facebook-opengraph, drupal-8

I am trying to add open graph meta tags dynamically to drupal 8 using the the page_attachments hook.

The meta tags are generated correctly however image and the website urls are being encoded by drupal and the result is broken links.

```
function module_page_attachments(array &$page)
{
  $tags = [
    ["name" => "twitter:card", "content" => "summary"],
    ["name" => "og:url", "content" => "https://example.net/index.php?param1=1&param2=2&param3=3"],
    ["name" => "og:title", "content" => "My title"],
    ["name" => "og:description", "content" => "My description"],
    ["name" => "og:image", "content" => "https://example.net/images?id=1&size=400"],
  ];

  foreach ($tags as $tag) {

    $headerTag = array(
      '#tag' => 'meta',
      '#attributes' => array(
        'property' => $tag['name'],
        'content' => $tag['content'],
      ),
    );
    $page['#attached']['html_head'][] = [$headerTag, $tag['name'] . "Id"];
  }
}
```

The result is the following

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta property="twitter:card" content="summary" />
    <meta property="og:url"
        content="https://example.com/index.php?param1=1&amp;param2=2&amp;param3=3" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="My title" />
    <meta property="og:description"
        content="My description" />
    <meta property="og:image"
        content="https://example.net/images?id=1&amp;size=400" />

</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

All the `&` characters have been encoded and transformed into `&amp;`. How can I prevent Drupal from encoding the characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an open ticket for issue with the status `needs work` on drupal's website.

**The issue can be found here:**

[www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2968558](http://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2968558)

A work around to solve the issue is to intercept the page and alter its template in the module file like the example here below shows:

file name: example.module

```
/**
 * Drupal bug caused the application to escape links. Therefore the og:image and og:url
 * were not working. Drupal kept converting `&` to `&amp;`
 * The solution here below converts the tags into inline templates
 */
function spa_seo_page_attachments_alter(array &$attachments)
{
  if (isset($attachments['#attached']['html_head'])) {
    foreach ($attachments['#attached']['html_head'] as $key => $item) {

      $property = !empty($item[0]['#attributes']['property']) ? $item[0]['#attributes']['property'] : '';

      if ($property == "og:url" || $property == "og:image") {
        $content = $item[0]['#attributes']['content'];
        $property = $item[0]['#attributes']['property'];
        $attachments['#attached']['html_head'][$key][0] = [
          '#type' => 'inline_template',
          '#template' => "{{ meta|raw }}",
          '#context' => [
            'meta' => '<meta property="' . $property . '" content="' . $content . '" />',
          ]
        ];
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Note**

Please note that `DrupalCoreRenderMarkup`does not solve the issue as this is a bug.

Answer (score 0):

[DrupalCoreRenderMarkup](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Markup.php/class/Markup/8.2.x) should do the trick:

```
<?php
use Drupal\Core\Render\Markup;

function module_page_attachments(array &$page)
{
  $tags = [
    ["name" => "twitter:card", "content" => "summary"],
    ["name" => "og:url", "content" => Markup::create("https://example.net/index.php?param1=1&param2=2&param3=3")],
    ["name" => "og:title", "content" => "My title"],
    ["name" => "og:description", "content" => "My description"],
    ["name" => "og:image", "content" => Markup::create("https://example.net/images?id=1&size=400")],
  ];

  foreach ($tags as $tag) {

    $headerTag = array(
      '#tag' => 'meta',
      '#attributes' => array(
        'property' => $tag['name'],
        'content' => $tag['content'],
      ),
    );
    $page['#attached']['html_head'][] = [$headerTag, $tag['name'] . "Id"];
  }
}
```